# information retrieval,precision and recall python

Tags: information-retrieval, cosine-similarity, precision-recall

Determine the average precision and recall for the ten queries and retrieve the top 10 documents.
for example:

ID of retrieve documents=[307 322 256 325 54 267 303 333 375 287]

ID of relevant documents=[11  99  100 307  54]

How to calculate precision and recall in payhton ?

Comment: Welcome  to SO. This question looks like a homework one. Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) . The question is unclear and does not show any effort from you to solve it. Please clarify your problem or delete the question.